# Why do I need to set both tail and tail->next to node to create a sorted merged list?

Tags: pointers, linked-list

I've found a nifty block of code to create a sorted merged list. However, there are two lines of code that I can't wrap my head around:

```
ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode dummy(0);
    ListNode *tail = &dummy;
    while(l1 && l2) {
        ListNode *& node = l1->val < l2->val? l1 : l2;
        tail->next = node;
        tail = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    tail->next = l1 ? l1 : l2;
    return dummy.next;
}
```

Why do we need to set `tail->next = node` before setting `tail = node`? I noticed that "tail = node" overwrites the assignment in the preceding line regardless.

But I've also noticed that my code breaks if I don't have "tail->next = node."

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to merge two linked lists in sorted order by value?

Comment: This actually isn't my code, but it's a working function to merge two lists into one sorted list. I know it works, but I'm not sure what's happening between "tail->next = node" and "tail = node."

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered my own question. In the first iteration of the while loop, `tail->next=node` is setting the dummy node's `next` address to node.

The following line, `tail=node`, is setting the tail itself to node. After doing this, you lose access to changing the dummy node's pointers, so you have to set this beforehand.